# Is it safe to use pip with a git repo?

Tags: python, github, pip

It is possible to use pip to install from a git repo using command
 `pip install git+https://github.com/...`

but is this safe for a production environment? Is there a way to protect from it being deleted without forking it, hosting myself, and merging any future updates?

Comment: What do you mean, "protect from it being deleted"? You can't control what the author of the software does with his repository. Neither can you control what the author of the software does with his PIP package.

Comment: I'm just imagining scenarios where anything could happen to this repo (user gets banned, deletes his account, removes repo) that I would no longer have access to it. With a package on PyPi, it seems more protected from some of these scenarios. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Git is decentralized, so noone keeps you from cloning the repo. Merging upstream changes is trivial in Git, that's a single shell command (you can run it via cron or something)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not 100% "safe", github can go down while you need to checkout the source, the author can delete the repository (or do some disrupting change to it) ecc. ecc.

With pip you can specify a revision or a tag together with the repository link

eg.
git+git://github.com/misterx/projectname.git@840d25bb9db9fbc801b9

this will checkout the revision 840d25bb9db9fbc801b9 no matter of the new versions so you do not end with unknown newer (broken) code.

What I normally do is to clone the project (unless I want to keep in sync with trunk) to my github account or somewhere else.